# Direct javascript printing from android & IOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, printing

I'm currently developing a web based application that requires RAW communication to printers straight from Javascript.

On the PC/Mac side of things I've had a great time implementing qz-print, a java based plugin for doing just this.

It's now come time that I look at how I can reproduce the same behaviour iOS and Android.

Here's some ideas that I've had so far:

1. Wait a god awful time for RawSockets (javascript TCPSocket implementation).
2. Build a simple android application to relay http requests to a tcpsocket (I'm getting started on this right now).
3. Use an existing Android/iOS app to achieve the above. I found "Let's Print Droid" which provides a HTTP server. It can send data to the printer but I can't seem to get the server part working. 
   From my web app I've tried sending POST and PUT requests with no luck and came across a CORS (Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing) issue. There is also no documentation for the LetsPrintDroid Http feature and to fix the CORS issue it would be up to the app to send specific headers to allow CORS.

Does anybody know of any awesome libraries, helper-apps or additional solutions?
What's your oppinion on the above solutions.

Any advice appreciated :-D

UPDATE:

I got a little android http-tcp socket running and it's working great!

The only obvious issue with this is that another app will be needed on IOS.
Thought it would be helpful so I've made the code available on Github:
https://github.com/micwallace/HttpSocketAdaptor

Answer (score 1):

The Lets print droid proxy server uses a multipart mime upload facility. The first part is the JSON string describing the printer as detailed in the help files. The second part is the data file.

Comment: I actually ended up implementing a similar solution, I did look at let's print Droid but must have missed this feature. My solution is a little broader as it basically allows socket communication using ajax calls. Thanks for sharing.